# Ionic Unable to add plugins. Perhaps your version of Cordova

Tags: cordova, installation

I cannot start a ionic app using command, on WinXp. 
I tried everything today. I'm trying to install is already three weeks.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\app>ionic start teste2
Creating Ionic app in folder C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\app\teste2 based on tabs project

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s

Update config.xml
Initializing cordova project
***Unable to add plugins. Perhaps your version of Cordova is too old. Try updating (npm install -g cordova), removing this project folder, and trying again. (CLI v
1.2.4)***
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a know issue, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7281

After install or update cordova with sudo, it changes the owner of user tmp dir to root.

Set the correct user to fix:

```
$sudo chown user:usergroup /home/user/tmp/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm ubuntu 14.04 but I had the same issue today. I had to run

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

From inside of the folder ionic created. Then I had to make sure my environment variables like JAVA_HOME were set. Not sure if this fixes your issues but hopefully it helps.